# I was trying to install "joomla" but i got 403 Forbidden error

Tags: joomla

I followed the rules on this link: http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/02/how-to-install-joomla-25x-on-ubuntu.html

I was doing well until it told me to run

```
cd /tmp && wget -O Joomla_2.5.7-Stable.zip http://goo.gl/41TMS
```

then it gave me this error:

```
--2012-12-20 09:33:48--  http://goo.gl/41TMS

Resolving goo.gl (goo.gl)... 173.194.69.139, 173.194.69.100, 173.194.69.101, ...

Connecting to goo.gl (goo.gl)|173.194.69.139|:80... connected.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden

2012-12-20 09:33:49 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by downloading the joomla package from it's official site then i extracted it and then i ran this command :

> gksudo nautilus

to become root in nautilus file manager, after that i copied everything that was extracted from joomla package, and i pasted it to : /var/www/joomla/ and then i ran this command:

> sudo chown -R www-data.www-data /var/www/joomla/

and i went to my browser and i opened :

> http:// localhost /joomla

and it took me to installation!
nice and easy